# Site marked as deceptive for Phishing, even when it is not

Tags: node.js, security, next.js, phishing

I have a social media site made with Next.js Typescript and Sanity CMS, which has been marked as deceptive site by google. When I searched for the sample URLs in the google search console, I found that those pages marked dangerous were the authentication ones readymade by Nextauth.js . Those pages are necessary for authentication of users and contain no malware or leaking information. How can I fix it?

The deceptive sample url shown are:

1. https://[*mywebsite.vercel.app*]/api/auth/callback/google
2. https://[*mywebsite.vercel.app*]/api/auth/signin/?error=OAuthCallback

Comment: This seems like a technical support question which you should be contacting Nextauth.js about, or Google, not random strangers on the Internet.